# String Compare and Deep Copy with Custom Struct and Pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-leaks, free

I'm currently trying to write a bunch of functions for a custom String struct without using the `string.h` library, but I'm having some difficulty implementing my struct in a couple of my functions--specifically, `copy_string(...)` and `compare_string(...)`. Essentially, these two functions should be doing the same things as `strcpy(...)` and `strcmp(...)` in C, but I want them to work with my basic String object that is defined below.

Here's the struct itself:

```
struct _String {

   char     *letters; // dynamically-allocated array to hold the characters
   uint32_t  count;   // number of characters in the string
};
typedef struct _String String;

/* IMPORTANT NOTE:
 *    String object S:
 *
 *    S.letters points to an array of dimension S.count + 1 and S.letters[S.count] == '\0'.
 *    If S.count > 0, then S.letters[0:S.count-1] hold the character letters for the string.
 */
```

Here is my current implementation of `copy_string` with comments describing what I want my function to do:

```
/** Makes an exact, full copy of a String.
*
* Pre:
*    *target is a String object
*    *source is a String object
*    target != source
* Post:
*    no memory leaks have occurred and
*    *target is a deep copy of *source
*    target->count = source->count
*    target->letters[i] == source->letters[i], i = 0 to target->count
*    target->letters != source->letters
*    *target is a String object
*
* Returns:
*    the count of target->letters
*    a negative value, if some error occurs
*/
int32_t copy_string(String* const target, const String* const source) {

    // int8_t count = 0;
    // while (source->letters[count] != '\0') { }

    if (source->letters == NULL)
        return -1;

    int i = 0;

    while (source->letters[i] != '\0') {

        target->letters[i] = source->letters[i];
        i++;

    }

    target->letters[target->count] = '\0';
    target->count = source->count;

    if (target->letters == NULL)
        return -2;

    return target->count;

}
```

Here is my current implementation of `compare_string` with comments describing what I want my function to do:

```
/** Compares two Strings.
 * 
 *  Pre:
 *    *first is a String object
 *    *second is a String object
 *
 *  Returns:
 *    < 0 if first precedes second based on ASCII values
 *      0 if first equals second
 *    > 0 if first follows second based on ASCII values
 */
int32_t compare_string(const String* const first, const String* const second) {

    while (first->letters && (first->letters == second->letters))
        first++, second++; // impossible due to const qualifiers

    return first->letters - second->letters    
}
```

I'm getting compilation errors like "member **count** is read-only object", memory leaks, and a bunch of other pointer-related problems. I literally started learning C four weeks ago, so please bear with me. Any critique and/or help would be great.

(UPDATE) Here's an example of how `string_compare` should work: String first is "cat" and String second is "elephant". The function should determine that "cat" != "elephant" and that "cat" is lexically going to precede "elephant" by using > or < to compare the String's ASCII values.

Comment: Why are you reinventing the wheel without using the string library?
If your objective is to study the language, I'd recommend to start with 
reading the source code of string.c.

Comment: I totally agree, but this is in preparation for a class project. I'm trying to understand why this code isn't working to hopefully help me understand the project specification better. We're essentially re-writing the string library in a reduced form, and writing these functions with the above struct is supposed to be prepping us for the project. Any tips for implementing the functions above?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Understood. BTW if your program causes memory leaks, can you provide the code which calls the functions? The caller is responsible for managing (allocating and freeing) memory.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use the struct member `count` to hold the length of the string?
It is considered to be redundant and we need to define the bahavior when the value of `count` conflicts with the actual length (the count of characters before the NUL character).

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot provide the testing code which is hosted on a code submission site. I believe a Valgrind call is used, and that is what detects the memory leakage. Supposedly, the testing code only makes calls to my functions with String objects based on the struct provided. Also, the functions are required to use the given struct, and the function parameters given are required for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0):

In the `copy_string()` function, you are referring the variable `target->count`
before it is assigned. Switch the order of the two sentences as:

```
target->count = source->count;
target->letters[target->count] = '\0';
```

In the `compare_string()` function, your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < first->count; i++) {
    if (*(first->letters + i) == *(second->letters + i))
        return 0;
}
```

returns `0` *immediately* after comparing the 1st characters only.
Instead please try something like:

```
int32_t compare_string(const String* const first, const String* const second) {

    int32_t i;
    while (1) {
        int32_t c1 = first->letters[i];
        int32_t c2 = second->letters[i];
        if (!c1) {              // end of string "first"
            if (!c2) {          // end of string "second", too
                break;          // both "first" and "second" ends
            } else {
                return -c2;     // "first" ends before "second"
            }
        } else if (!c2) {       // "second" ends before "first"
            return c1;
        } else if (c1 != c2) {  // the characters differ
            return c1 - c2;     // return the difference
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 0;                   // exact match
}
```

Judging from your comment, memory leaks seem not to be your responsibility.

Comment: I appreciate your response. In the `compare_string` function, the order of the two Strings is based on which one comes first alphabetically (or in C's case, ordered by the ASCII values). I believe your code only compares single given letters from each String at a time. Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.
I'd like you to clarify your concern with my code. Can you provide some sets of two strings to be compared and the expected results to demonstrate your requirements?
Please include them by editing your question, not as a comment.
I'll be back after 7 hours coz it's high time in my timezone. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question. Although the additional information is
limited, I'm sure my `compare_string` works well as you expect. actually I've
tested it behaves exactly same as the library `strcmp` function.
I still don't get your concern with my function. I strongly recommend to write your
own test code (main function) to call the functions, compile it, and run before
submitting the functions to the host. Otherwise you cannot tell what is the problem.

Comment: I apologize for the limited information, and you are correct in saying that I should be doing some manual testing.